# Program crash with removal of SDL_PollEvent

Tags: c++, sdl-2

Why does my program crash when i remove the SDL_PollEvent line from main?  I wanted to keep input management in my gamesystem class without using events.

I have also tried putting the !gamesystem.boot() within the while statement itself as well to no avail.

Main:

```
int main(int argc, char* args[])
{
    if(!init())
    {
        printf("Failed to initialize!\n");
    }
    else
    {
        GameSystem gamesystem;
        gamesystem.startup(gRenderer,gGameController1,gGameController2);
        bool quit = false;
        SDL_Event e;
        while(!quit)
        {
            while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0)
            {
                if(e.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    quit = true;
                }
            }
            if(!gamesystem.boot())
                quit = true;
        }
    }
    close();
    return 0;
}
```

gamesystem:

```
#include "GameSystem.h"

GameSystem::GameSystem()
{
}

void GameSystem::startup(SDL_Renderer* gRenderer, SDL_Joystick* gGameController1, SDL_Joystick* gGameController2)
{
    gameRenderer = gRenderer;
    controller1 = gGameController1;
    controller2 = gGameController2;
    title.loadFile(gameRenderer, "Art/Title.png");
    arrow.loadFile(gameRenderer, "Art/Arrow.png");
    beep = Mix_LoadWAV("SFX/Beep.wav");
    boop = Mix_LoadWAV("SFX/Boop.wav");
    buup = Mix_LoadWAV("SFX/Buup.wav");
    baap = Mix_LoadWAV("SFX/Baap.wav");
}

bool GameSystem::boot()
{
    renderClear();
    if(menu == 0)
    {
        title.render(gameRenderer, 0,0);
        if(selection == 0)
            arrow.render(gameRenderer, 215, 400);
        else if(selection == 1)
            arrow.render(gameRenderer, 250, 440);
        else if(selection == 2)
            arrow.render(gameRenderer, 235, 482);
        else if(selection == 3)
            arrow.render(gameRenderer, 255, 528);
    }
    update();
    return quit;
}

enum buttons GameSystem::controls()
{
    const Uint8 *state = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);
    if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_DOWN] || SDL_JoystickGetHat(controller1, 0) == SDL_HAT_DOWN)
        return u;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_UP] || SDL_JoystickGetHat(controller1, 0) == SDL_HAT_UP)
        return d;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_LEFT] || SDL_JoystickGetHat(controller1, 0) == SDL_HAT_LEFT)
        return l;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_RIGHT] || SDL_JoystickGetHat(controller1, 0) == SDL_HAT_RIGHT)
        return r;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_X] || SDL_JoystickGetButton(controller1, 0))
        return a;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_C] || SDL_JoystickGetButton(controller1, 1))
        return b;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_S] || SDL_JoystickGetButton(controller1, 2))
        return x;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_D] || SDL_JoystickGetButton(controller1, 3))
        return y;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_RETURN])
        return start;
    else if(state [SDL_SCANCODE_SPACE])
        return select;


    return nopress;
}
void GameSystem::renderClear()
{
    SDL_SetRenderDrawColor(gameRenderer, 0, 0, 0, 0xFF);
    SDL_RenderClear(gameRenderer);
}

void GameSystem::update()
{
    switch(controls())
    {
    case u:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,beep,0);
        selection++;
        if(selection > 3) selection = 0;
        break;
    case d:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,beep,0);
        selection--;
        if(selection < 0) selection = 3;
        break;
    case l:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,beep,0);
        break;
    case r:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,beep,0);
        break;
    case a:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,beep,0);
        if(selection == 3) quit = false;
        break;
    case b:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,boop,0);
        break;
    case x:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,buup,0);
        break;
    case y:
        Mix_PlayChannel(-1,baap,0);
        break;
    }
    //takes in vector of things to render after they have been sorted and renders them//

    //^render vector here^//
    SDL_RenderPresent(gameRenderer);
}
```

Comment: do you only remove the LINE :  while(SDL_PollEvent(&e)!=0) ? So it is still checking the (now undefined) e.type ?

Comment: You should use a debugger to figure out where crash happens. As question stands, it is unclear what your code is, what kind of crash you're talking about, and even if it is a crash at all or just window manager message that window not responts to its messages (because without PumpEvents it isn't, but it is far from being called a 'crash').

Comment: Hi and thanks for the replies, for the first question i remove the entirety of while(SDL_PollEvent) including if(e.type) and SDL_Event e, and for more clarity, it runs and opens the window with the title image, but immediately after it becomes unresponsive and the only thing left to do is close it, the debugger also just finished with status 0 so I'm still not sure what's going on, i can add anything else if you guys think it'll help, thanks a bunch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your program does not crash, it is just ignoring inputs (it is "not responding"). It will just run `gamesystem.boot()` repeatedly without ever detecting your imputs.

Actually, [`SDL_PollEvent()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PollEvent) internally calls [`SDL_PumpEvents()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_PumpEvents) which updates inputs. When you remove `SDL_PollEvent()`, SDL never updates its internal input device state, so `SDL_GetKeyboardState()` always returns its initial state.

Replacing your PollEvent loop with `SDL_PumpEvents()` should solve this.

Comment: Thank you so much for the clarification, it was driving me mad why it was doing that lol